# PayPal PHP SDK Payment crash on 500

Tags: php, paypal

*bsd*

Hello, I am using the Paypal PHP SDK to connect with paypal. I am on a shared hosting account - linux system.

I have set up everything and it seems to be ok... but when it gets to the `$payment->create` method it produces an 500 error.

Is there something I am missing? also, How can I check to see if the apiContext is connecting ok?

```
require __DIR__  . '/sdk/autoload.php';

// requiring SDK uses

$api = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
            '...',     // ClientID
            '...'      // ClientSecret
        )
);

$api->setConfig([
    'mode' => 'sandbox',
    'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
    'log.LogEnabled' => false,
    'log.FileName' => '',
    'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE',
    'validation.level' => 'log'
]);

// setting up payer, details, amount, transaction, redirectUrls etc...

$payment->create($api); // crashes on a 500 error
```

Is there something I should check on the hosting setup? how can I debug apiContext?

I haven't used composer, is this a problem?

Still haven't found a solution for this problem, any help would be great

This is the log export

this is the log output -

```
[24-07-2017 11:15:44] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
[24-07-2017 11:15:44] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : DEBUG: Request Headers     : 
[24-07-2017 11:15:44] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : DEBUG: Request Data        : grant_type=client_credentials
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[24-07-2017 11:15:44] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 0
[24-07-2017 11:15:44] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : DEBUG: Response Headers    : 
[24-07-2017 11:15:44] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : ERROR: Got Http response code 0 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token. 
[24-07-2017 11:15:44] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : DEBUG: 

================================================================================================================================
```

Comment: Possible to add the log here?

Comment: thanks for the comment, I have added the log

Comment: First, could you try to run this from CLI and check the result? `curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token 
   -H "Accept: application/json" 
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" 
   -u "client_id:secret" 
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"`

Comment: @MaxChernopolsky I am running a shared hosting, don't have a CLI

Comment: is your server has `openssl` extension installed? installation prerequisites [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Installation)

Comment: @elegisandi yes openssl is enabled

Comment: I think that you have the issue with the time out.Can you try out the following configuration(I'v used it on my project and works fine).

Comment: $apiContext->setConfig(
        array(
            'mode' => 'sandbox',
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => '../PayPal.log',
            'log.LogLevel' => 'DEBUG',
            'cache.enabled' => true,
        )
    );

Comment: @Arslan.H its not working still, I have updated the log in the question

Comment: @levi i had so much problems with integrating PayPal...Errors sometimes happens sometimes don't, that was the most frustrating part.I'l try to start up my old project to see what can be done here..

Comment: @levi also can you put more of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of an old topic, but since I stumbled on this one, here is what caused the problem for me.

The payment method uses `openssl_encrypt` to encrypt the data. When using openssl_encrypt with FreeBSD based systems (including MacOS X Mojave + MacPorts), the calls to `openssl_encrypt` fails in PHP 7.3.

[See discussion](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/291589114aa9be899cf7d5d874c3b5bbdb35f336#diff-67e997bcfdac55191033d57a16d1408a).

Answer (score 0):

I had an 500 error too in my project. My problem was related with an tls issue, which has to be 1.2 to fulfil the pci-dss. https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update  ist the official statement to it by PayPal. Maybe your web server runs on 1.0 too.

Comment: is having https or ssl a requirement? is tls ssl related? ... I have simple shared hosting account.

Comment: Yes. You will need at least http 1.1 for all connections and tls 1.2 on https. I think phpinfo will dump your current versions. Btw I don't use https and it is working. Maybe your Hoster can help you. Otherwise u can test it locally.

Comment: Hello I have talked with my shared hosting and they said that its not supposed to be a problem, do you know a way I could debug this whole process? like a test connection on the apiContext or some sort?

Comment: Please note that this is also found on google when searching "do I have to have SSL to sell with PayPal" - Do I need SSL for Paypal?
"SSL certificates are needed to protect your customers information, so if your website does not collect any information, and uses only PayPal as the payment gateway, then NO, you DO NOT need an SSL certificate because all of your customers information is being passed through the PayPal website, which is already ...Sep 15, 2010"

Answer (score 0):

Try this: in a file `PayPalHttpConfig.php` (located in `Paypal/Core`) Change

```
CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 6,
```

to

```
CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 1,
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a HTTPS proxy so the Origin header is http on localhost